# Calculate this limit without using L'Hôpital rule ..Any suggestions( I got to the solution with the suggestions, why do you close the questions?)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I can't think of any change of variable to solve this limit, I can't use derivatives or series. Can you please guide me on how to do it?
Thank you

$$\underset {x\to 6} {\text {lim}}\frac {x -\sqrt[3] {x + 2} - \sqrt {3 x - 2}} {x -\sqrt[3] {4 x + 3} - \sqrt {x + 3}}$$

**Edit
taking the suggestion of @Paramanand Singh
making x=6+h , x->6 ,h->0  I arrive at the following  ??**

$$\underset {h\to
     0} {\text {lim}}\frac {(h + 
     6) - \sqrt[3] {h + 6 + 2} - \sqrt {3 (h + 6) - 2}} {(h + 
     6) - \sqrt[3] {4 (h + 6) + 3} - \sqrt {h + 6 + 3}}$$

$$\underset {h\to 0
     } {\text {lim}}\frac {(h + 
     6) - \sqrt[3] {h + 8} - \sqrt {3 h + 16}} {(h + 
     6) - \sqrt[3] {4 h + 27} - \sqrt {h + 9}}$$

$$\displaystyle \huge \lim_{h->0}\frac{\frac{(h+6)-\sqrt[3]{8+h}-\sqrt{3h+16}}{h}}{\frac{(h+6)-\sqrt[3]{4h+27}-\sqrt{h+9}}{h}}$$

**Edit 2  : by manipulating the numerator and denominator, I get 4 limits and when I develop them individually I reach the desired result.  Thanks to all**

Comment: Try to rationalize the expression.

Comment: @ Somos , the result is 0/0

Comment: @ Fran Cruz I thought about it, but it is extremely long, and almost always these limits can be reduced by changing the variable.,

Comment: Context is needed here.  Were you specifically assigned this problem from a book or class with the understanding that L'Hopital's Rule was outlawed?  If so, there must have been some theorems or previously solved problems leading up to this problem that would be pertinent here.  I'd like to buy a vowel?

Comment: @user2661923 9 no, it's a problem taken from the net, it's not homework, just learning for me.  It says clear without L'Hopital's Rule ,the suggestion they give use suitable auxiliary variable.

Comment: Nice rebuttal.  In effect, this problem is akin to contest math, where **all bets are off** and the creative solution can take any form.  If it were me, I would first spend 30 minutes on it.  Then, I would post a mathSE query that **included my efforts**, which you have not done.  Then, I would bite the bullet and stop pouring good time after bad and wait for someone to post an answer to learn from, if ever.

Comment: @user2661923ok, I'll try, let's see if I come up with something.any suggestions?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\,(1+x)^r=1 + r\,x+O(x^2)\,$ where $\,r\,$ is real?

Comment: @Somos,Using what you tell me, I arrive at the result I had already thought of, deriving it as well, but I'm stuck on how to use the suggestion to solve the limit.

Comment: A simple algebra helps here. Just write $x=6+h,h\to 0$ and divide both numerator and denominator by $h$. You should be able to proceed without much issue. Please edit your post to include efforts based on this and let me know if you get stuck. Posting just problem statements is discouraged here.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh ,thanks for your answer, I will do it and publish my result.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh , **(view edition)**  I get to that step, what do you advise me to do next?

Comment: haven’t thought this through all the way, but what if u multiply by $1/x^6$ on top and bottom. then bring terms inside radicals and see what happens

Comment: I am glad that you were finally able to solve the problem yourself with my suggestion.

Comment: By the way I was not notified of your replies because you have a space between "@" and my username. There should be no spaces there.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh thanks for your initial indication, at first I did not see it, then I was enlightened, by chance do you have any guide where limits appear like this, where you do not have to use derivatives of Taylor expansions only ingenuity (I have seen that many apply l'hopital so it comes out, but really do not understand anything of the rule, only mechanics).

Answer (score 1):

Well one way(which may not be satisfactory to you) is to expand the numerator and denominator about $x=6$. We get the following result for the numerator
$$x-\sqrt{3x-2}-\sqrt[3]{x+2} = \frac{13}{24}(x-6)+O((x-6)^2)$$
and for the denominator
$$x - \sqrt{x+3} - \sqrt[3]{4x+3} = \frac{37}{54}(x-6)+O((x-6)^2)$$
And therefore the result is after dividing and neglecting the higher order terms $\frac{117}{148}$.

For what it's worth, [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%5Cfrac%7Bx-%5Csqrt%7B3x-2%7D-%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%2B2%7D%7D%7Bx%20-%20%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B3%7D%20-%20%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B4x%2B3%7D%7D%20as%20x%20%5Cto%206) gives the same result.

Comment: @tmaj_Thanks for your answer, but I am trying to find a suitable replacement according to the suggestion of the author of the problem (Taken from the net).